# VirtualEnv - Local Package installed but module not found

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am currently facing a problem with VirtualEnvs and Local Modules.

I have created a module name MyModule. I have created a Virtual Environment and installed it. However, the module is not found.

But when I run:

```
$ python -m pip freeze
MyModule==1.0.0
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
```

It tells me that MyModule is installed. I know I am running the correct virtual env. I had run `which python`, and it shows that I am in the correct environment.

I had tried the following commands:

`python /Path/To/MyModule/setup.py install`

and

`python -m pip install MyModule --no-index --find-links=/Path/To/ MyModule`

They say the module is installed correctly.

Can anyone help??

Many Thanks

Comment: So how did you import your module?

Comment: import MyModule

Comment: No, probably a typo when I was writing the question, I have not copy and paste, sorry :/ But the module was installed under the correct name, has the pip freeze shows

Comment: That's weird... you just get an `ImportError`, right? You could import your module from elsewhere, correct? (just to be sure it's not a problem in the module)

Comment: I got the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyModule'`

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in your module? If yes, has it some content? And I guess you are in Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed the package in the root and it worked, and in another computers also. Just does not work in the virtualenv :/

Comment: the __init__.py is empty

Comment: Hm, strange. Just to be clear: you are in your venv as confirmed by `pip list`, start a Python prompt, enter `import MyModule` and get a `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: Ok, I had to install the package from the directory where the `setup.py` file is

Comment: So it works now? And yes, this is how you have to install it locally.

Comment: Yap, it simply works now... I do not understand why... Any ideas?

Comment: So how did you install it before? You tried to install it from another directory?

Comment: To install a package locally from source you can `python setup.py install` or `pip install MyPackage`. Both imply that you are in the root path of your package, where `setup.py` is located.